# How do I change my program to end an incorrect output from continuously being printed to the console?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Im coding a Rock Paper Scissors program and eveything works completely fine except for one thing. In the line of the else condition, the one that contains the while loop `(choice > 3 && choice < 1)`  it only ever works when an inncorect input like 4 is entered once but not a second time.

When an incorrect input is entered the first time the program will ask for the input again but if you enter another inncorrect input it will just continously just keep printing the same printf line

`printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");`  and then proceed to just keep printing

`Computer choice is ROCK. Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, randNum, seed, choice;
  int counter = 0;
  int counterUser = 0;
  int counterComputer = 0;

  printf("Please enter the random number generator seed.\n");

  /* ANY integer value can be given as a seed */

  scanf("%d", &seed);

  /* Seed the random number generator */
  srand(seed);


  /* Counter to ensure only 10 games are played */

  while (counter != 10) {

    for (i=0;i<1;i++) {
      /* Generate a random number and restrict it to the range 1 to 3 */
      randNum = rand()%3+1;
      /*printf("A random number between 1 and 3: %d\n", randNum);*/
    }

    printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);


    /* User picks an option */

    if ( choice == 1 ){
      printf("User choice is ROCK.\n");
    }
    else if ( choice == 2 ){
      printf("User choice is PAPER.\n");
    }
    else if ( choice == 3 ){
      printf("User choice is SCISSORS.\n");
    }  
    else {
      while (choice > 3 && choice < 1){
        printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);        
      }     
    }  


    /* Computer choses an option */

    if ( randNum == 1 ){
      printf("Computer choice is ROCK.\n");
    }
    else if ( randNum == 2 ){
      printf("Computer choice is PAPER.\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("Computer choice is SCISSORS.\n");
    }  


    /* Compare the user and computers choices */

    if ( randNum == 1 && choice == 1){
      printf("It's a draw. Computer chose ROCK and User also chose ROCK.\n");
    }
    else if ( randNum == 2 && choice == 2 ){
      printf("It's a draw. Computer chose PAPER and User also chose PAPER.\n");
    }
    else if ( randNum == 3 && choice == 3 ){
      printf("It's a draw. Computer chose SCISSORS and User also chose SCISSORS.\n");
    }
    else if ( randNum == 1 && choice == 2 ){
      printf("User wins because PAPER beats ROCK.\n");
      counterUser = counterUser + 1;
    }
    else if ( randNum == 1 && choice == 3 ){
      printf("Computer wins because ROCK beats SCISSORS.\n");
      counterComputer = counterComputer + 1;
    }
    else if ( randNum == 2 && choice == 3 ){
      printf("User wins because SCISSORS beats PAPER.\n");
      counterUser = counterUser + 1;    
    }
    else if ( randNum == 3 && choice == 2 ){
      printf("Computer wins because SCISSORS beats PAPER.\n");
      counterComputer = counterComputer + 1;      
    }
    else if ( randNum == 2 && choice == 1 ){
      printf("Computer wins because PAPER beats ROCK.\n");
      counterComputer = counterComputer + 1;    
    }
    else if ( randNum == 3 && choice == 1 ){
      printf("User wins because ROCK beats SCISSORS.\n");
      counterUser = counterUser + 1;    
    }                
    else {
    }  

  counter = counter + 1;

  }

printf("In 10 games, computer won %d", counterComputer);
printf(" times");
printf(" and user won %d", counterUser);
printf(" times.");

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I've tweaked it now so the only problem is now getting rid of the `Computer choice is ___`  when i input 4 or another inncorect value

```
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
2
User choice is PAPER.
Computer choice is ROCK.
User wins because PAPER beats ROCK.
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
4
Computer choice is PAPER.
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
4
Computer choice is ROCK.
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
4
Computer choice is ROCK.
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
```

This is the if statement that follows the code above and is outputing its responses when i dont want it to because when i enter or 4 or antoher incorrect value these responses should not be printing to the console aswell

```
    /* Computer choses an option */

    if ( randNum == 1 ){
      printf("Computer choice is ROCK.\n");
    }
    else if ( randNum == 2 ){
      printf("Computer choice is PAPER.\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("Computer choice is SCISSORS.\n");
    }
```

Sorry for not phrasing it properly before, so how do i get the the line `Computer choice is ___`  to stop printing because 4 is an incorrect value and hence the `Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.` line should just appear on its own

Comment: I think your second while needs to be a do-while

Comment: Also the condition (choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3) doesn't make sense because it will always be true since choice cannot be 1, 2, and 3 the same time.

Comment: C# is not C just because they start with the same letter, any more than a car, a cat and a carrot are the same because they start with the first two letters. Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your post. Tags have relevance and meaning here, so abusing them is inappropriate. Thanks.

Comment: Also, stepping through the code in a debugger will help you solve this problem yourself. It's never too early to learn to use the debugger - it's the most powerful tool a coder has in their toolbox for figuring out logic errors in their code.

Comment: Sorry for using the C# tag, I'm new to C programming so i thought they were more or less the same

Comment: Update the code snippet to a version showing the entire content of you first while loop

Comment: Yeah I just did that now, I just didnt want to upload the entire code so it wouldnt look too confusing for anyone trying to read it

Comment: The problem is in the condition of your while (choice>3 && choice<1). It should be an Or (||) because you want to ask new input if the choice is > 3 or < than 1

Comment: omg thank u so much, its working completely fine now, all problems fixed.

Comment: Sorry for the horrible question layout, i wasnt sure what to include and what not to but thanks now:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're checking whether the user's input is valid or not at the very end. you should move the while loop:

```
while (choice > 3 && choice < 1){
   printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");
   scanf("%d", &choice);        

}
```

above the if statement:

```
if ( choice == 1 ){
      printf("User choice is ROCK.\n");

}else if ( choice == 2 ){
      printf("User choice is PAPER.\n");

}else if ( choice == 3 ){
      printf("User choice is SCISSORS.\n");

}
```

So when the user inputs an invalid number, it will go over the if statement and then it will ask again. Once it gets a valid input i'll go to check the computers move and not print the users move.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you were trying to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void state_machine(int *choice, int user);
void request_input(int* choice);

char array[3][20] = {"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"};

int main() {

    int counter = 0, randNum = 0, choice = 0, counterUser = 0, counterComputer = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (counter < 10) {

        randNum = rand()%3+1;
        request_input(&choice);
        state_machine(&choice, 1);
        state_machine(&randNum, 2);

        if(randNum == choice) {
            printf("It's a draw. Computer chose %s and User also chose %s.\n", array[randNum-1],array[choice-1]);
        }
        else if ( randNum == 1 && choice == 2 || randNum == 2 && choice == 3 || randNum == 3 && choice == 1) {
            printf("User wins because %s beats %s.\n", array[choice-1], array[randNum-1]);
            counterUser = counterUser + 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("Computer wins because %s beats %s.\n", array[randNum-1], array[choice-1]);
            counterComputer = counterComputer + 1;      
        }
        counter++;
    }
    printf("In %d games, computer won %d times and user won %d  times.", counter, counterComputer, counterUser);
    return 0;
}

void request_input(int* choice) {
    printf("Please choose 1 for %s, 2 for %s or 3 for %s.\n",  array[0],  array[1],  array[2]);
    scanf("%d", choice);
}

void state_machine(int *choice, int user) {
    if(*choice < 1 || *choice > 3) {
        printf("Invalid Selection was made.\n");
        request_input(choice);
        state_machine(choice,1);
    }    
    else if(user == 1) {
        printf("User choice is %s.\n", array[*choice-1]);
    }
    else if(user == 2) {
        printf("Computer choice is %s.\n", array[*choice-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is what my original problem was but its all fixed now, the problem was just a condition that was supposed to be || and not &&. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

`(choice > 3 && choice < 1)` should never work as it is impossible for it to satisfy both predicates.  Think, for it to succeed, you need first `choice` to be greater than `3`.  Let's assume it is `4`, and evaluate the second test (`4` is never less than `1`, so the second test fails)

No number can be at the same time greater than `3` and less than `1`, so the test you have written is always false (as if you had written `if (false)` instead)  Every number that is greater than `3` is also greater than `1`, and you are asking for a number less than `1` that is greater than `3`.  It cannot even work for the case of `4` you state in the question.